# Changing a pane's content from within?

Tags: java, javafx

If I have a class that extends superclass that has a `.setContent(Pane pane)` method, am I able to change the `pane` from within the class.

For example: When the example button is pushed, I would like to set the content to `stackPane2`. (`this.setContent(stackPane2);`).

```
public class AClass extends SomeClass{
    public AClass(){
        super();
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        Button exampleButton = new Button("Example");
        exampleButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //Change the content here
            }
        });


        StackPane stackPane1 = new StackPane();
        stackPane1.getChildren().addAll(hBox);

        StackPane stackPane2 = new StackPane();
        stackPane2.getChildren().add(/*Some other stuff*/);

        this.setContent(stackPane1);
    }
}
```

Can this be done? If so, how? Otherwise what could be a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i missing something, but i think that the easiest way if you don't have some much code is declare `stackPane1` and `stackPane2` as final fields and then call `setContent` from the button listener.

```
public class AClass extends SomeClass{

private final StackPane stackPane1;
private final StackPane stackPane2;

public AClass(){
    super();
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    Button exampleButton = new Button("Example");
    exampleButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (somenthingHapper()) {
                this.setContent(stackPane1);
            } else {
                this.setContent(stackPane2);
            }
        }
    });


    stackPane1 = new StackPane();
    stackPane1.getChildren().addAll(hBox);

    stackPane2 = new StackPane();
    stackPane2.getChildren().add(/*Some other stuff*/);

    this.setContent(stackPane1);
}
}
```